# custom button in Visual force

Tags: custom-button

We've a custom button, created using "Buttons, Links, and Actions" option available via Set up.

This button is executing javascript( if value of field = 'x' , then update value of some other field 'y' )

This is existing logic and working well.

Now we've to convert the view page to Visual force because of some other requirement.How can I put above button in VF Page. 
I was trying something like this :

```
<apex:page standardController="MyCustomObj__c" >
  <apex:form >
  <apex:commandButton="{!URLFOR($Action.MyCustomObj__c.UpdateValue, MyCustomObj__c.Id)}" value="MyButton" />

<!--UpdateValue is Name of custom button created via Set up -->

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

But this is not working ,the page seems to be getting submitted and I got this error :

> URL No Longer Exists You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer
>   exists on salesforce.com.

What I'm doing wrong ? 
One solution could be to put javascript from button to visual force page. but I I don't want to do that as this javascript could change later on and I don't want to change VF page , just to change Javascript.

I would like as preferred solution,to use that Custom button created via set up,  'as it is' in my Visual force( so that it executes javascript) but not finding any way.

Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you just create this button in VF page?

Comment: Hi ...See this is existing button . even If I recreate in VF, you want to suggest that I should write javascript  in VF page or in some JS file ? As I mentioned, this is not a preferrable solution for us

Comment: A good middle-ground for you would probably be to write your javascript as a function in a static resource. It can then be included in your button using {!REQUIRESCRIPT() } and can be included in your VF page with <apex:includeScript />. The only part that will be different between your custom button and your VF button will be how the function is called. The Custom Button execution is controlled by Salesforce. In your VF page, you could just use an onclick on your <apex:commandButton /> to invoke the function.